# MYSQL Find the next seq_num from a table of ID and seq_num

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have two tables

alt holds all the IDs and seq_nums

QRY hold a subset of IDs and seq_nums

I need to find the next seq_num from alt for each ID, seq_num pair from QRY.

I would also like to include the ID/Seq_num pair from QRY if possible.

This code just gives me 1 result, I need 1 result for each ID/seq_num pair.

I am using MYSQL Workbench 6.3.7

I show an example of the 2 tables and the result I am looking for.

```
SELECT alt.seq_num,
    `alt.id`
FROM alt
inner join 
d. QRY on QRY. id =  alt.id
where alt.seq_num > QRY.id
order by seq_num ASC
Limit 1
;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is this you are searching for?

```
select id, max(seq_num) next_seq_num
from alt
group by id
union
select id, seq_num
from qry;
```

**edit**

```
select alt.id, min(alt.seq_num) next_seq_num
from alt
    inner join qry on alt.id = qry.id and alt.seq_num > qry.seq_num
group by alt.id
union
select id, seq_num
from qry;
```

Comment: Does MAX(seq_num) get the highest value seq_num for the ID?

Comment: So, in my example: for ID=26 I want to get seq_num 666 not 668 or 671.  I don't understand how the max function will find the next highest seq_num for that ID.

Comment: How do you determine next seq for id 26 = 666?  What is the logic, I don't understand.

Comment: There are multiple seq_nums for each ID, as in the example table "alt".  In the QRY table it only has ID =26 and seq_num = 662.  I want the next highest seq_num for id =26, which would be seq_num = 666.  I don't want the highest or lowest, but the next in the sequence.

Comment: No, it still is using min or max , but the idea of Union is very good.  Thanks

Comment: `min()` with `alt.seq_num > qry.seq_num` should take the next seq number from alt table.  What is the result of that query?

Comment: If you don't want min() or max(), this is possible with ranking function.